# package 'Rbbg' is not available (for R version 2.15.2)

Tags: r, bloomberg

How do I find out for which versions of R this package *is* available?

```
> install.packages("Rbbg", repos = "http://r.findata.org")
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://r.findata.org/src/contrib
Warning message:
package 'Rbbg' is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know? Email the package and/or repository maintainer(s).

Comment: I immediately see at least 3 reasons for posting here: (1) there may be people who know [other than you], (2) there may be a workaround that does not require an answer, and (3) if answered, this can be helpful to others.

Comment: Unfortunately, I agree with Joshua.  This is not a programming question.  I'm voting to close as off-topic

Comment: I think this would be a more generally interesting question if it applied to formerly-CRAN-available packages:  RBbg is a bit of a special case http://findata.org/rbloomberg/

Comment: Technically it may not be a programming question, but I'm sure glad it was here. So maybe there is some merit to it's existence.

Comment: semantically it may not be a programming question, but I'd sure like to know the answer to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find out by browsing the bin directory at http://r.findata.org/

You're using Windows, right?

---

The source code for Rbbg is available on github at https://github.com/johnlaing/blpwrapper

Comment: Yes, win64. Should I downgrade my R to 2.15.0?

Comment: FWIW, I was able to install it in R-2.15.1with the command you gave.  After upgrading to R-2.15.2 it's "not available".  Might be worth sending an e-mail to the maintainer to get an up-to-date version on the repos.

Comment: that's actually a bit funny, because the R `available.packages()` function doesn't (as far as I'm aware) discriminate between minor (point) R releases, and there's not a built-in dependency on R > 2.15.1 ( http://r.findata.org/bin/windows64/contrib/2.15/PACKAGES ) , so there must be something slightly non-standard going on ... ?  (Unless I'm misunderstanding the rules for Windows binary packages in some way)

Comment: @BenBolker that was my understanding too. I'm a bit puzzled.  (but I don't use Windows when I don't have to)

Comment: I have this problem all the time on Windows, but because I have a mirror install on linux I install problematic packages on linux, they then become available on Windows, but it sure is an annoyance.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the issue here that is non-standard is it's looking for source by default, rather than binary.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://r.findata.org/src/contrib
```

http://r.findata.org/src/ does not exist, but http://r.findata.org/bin does