# Download vs Compile: the Rbbg Package

Tags: r, bloomberg

The Rbbg package facilitates data downloads from Bloomberg and provides an interface to the R programming language.

where can i get the download for R version 3.0.2??? Will a compile from source facilitate use under the new version of R??? If so, please advise on details

Comment: possible duplicate of [package 'Rbbg' is not available (for R version 2.15.2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807729/package-rbbg-is-not-available-for-r-version-2-15-2)

Comment: still looking for an answer…the link you shared is not helpful

Comment: Did you download a binary file (http://r.findata.org/bin/windows64/contrib/) or the source code (https://github.com/johnlaing/blpwrapper)?  Try `install.pacakges("path/to/file", repos=NULL)` or [build yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages/11105132#11105132).  If none of that helps, please provide more detail about what problem you're having.